# Proving the given condition in a triangle

Tags: geometry

I have the following problem with me:

> Let $ABC$ be an acute angled triangle with circumcircle $\omega$ centered at $O$. Let $AD$,$BE$ and $CF$ be altitudes of $ABC$.
>   Let line $EF$ meet $\omega$ at $P$ and $Q$.
>   If $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$.
>   Prove that $AP^2 = 2AD\cdot OM$.

My try:

I proved that $AO$ is perpendicular to $PQ$. Now the given condition is equivalent to telling that I need to prove $AP^2 = AH*AD$, since $AH = 2OM$, where $H$ is the orthocentre of triangle $ABC$ which implies that I need to prove that triangle $APH$ should be similar to $ADP$ which is possible if angle $APH$ is proved to be equal to angle $ADP$. How do I do this?

Comment: What is point H in the question ?

Comment: @RahulRamachandran H stands for the orthocentre, thought it was a standard notation so used it directly, added that info in the question